# Withings API and C#

Tags: c#

I try to connect my home automation in c# with Withings but I don't achieve to do this.

I try [this library](https://github.com/cgiovanacci/withings) but it doesn't work, the URL doesn't contain key or secret.

I try to use RestSharp :

```
        RestClient client = new RestClient(baseUrl)
        {
            Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForRequestToken(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
        };
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("account/request_token", Method.POST);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        NameValueCollection qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(response.Content);
        string oauthToken = qs["oauth_token"];
        string oauthTokenSecret = qs["oauth_token_secret"];

        PackageHost.WriteInfo("{0}", response.Content);

        const string verifier = "5179055";

        request = new RestRequest("account/access_token");
        client.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForAccessToken(
            consumerKey, consumerSecret, oauthToken,
            oauthTokenSecret, verifier);
        response = client.Execute(request);

        Assert.NotNull(response);
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);

        qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(response.Content);
        oauthToken = qs["oauth_token"];
        oauthTokenSecret = qs["oauth_token_secret"];
```

I succeed to authorize my application but I don't get the access token or secret. It says "Invalid verifier" but I get this verifier from authorization page, in url.

Anyone succeed to connect Withings with .net ?

Thank for your help.

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Comment: No I always  have problem on getting access token or secret

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been having the same issue. I decided on using [Quantfabric](https://github.com/lukedoolittle/quantfabric). You can see my [post on Medium](https://antarrbyrd.com/oauth-authorization-in-net-with-quantfabric-de7d3819ce1e#.n2p2ou6qm), for instructions on how to use.